# Having trouble getting DataSnapshot from database and getting null values

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to view a users story post by pressing their story button, navigating me to the full page storyView to see the images. I think I am having trouble passing the data to the next page or querying the data from the database. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

This is the error I'm getting:

> The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder:
> type '(DataSnapshot) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f''

This is where I'm calling the data to be retrieved on the actual page where you would view the image. The error is pointing to the crudMethods.getStoryListData() line

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:link_me/services/crud.dart';
import "package:story_view/story_view.dart";

class StoryPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String currentUser;
  final String storyUrl;

  StoryPageView({this.currentUser, this.storyUrl});

  @override
  _StoryPageViewState createState() => _StoryPageViewState();
}

class _StoryPageViewState extends State<StoryPageView> {
  CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();
  List<String> itemList = new List();
  final StoryController controller = StoryController();
  

  QuerySnapshot storySnapshot;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();

    crudMethods.getStoryListData().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      //storySnapshot = result;
      var urlData = snapshot.value;
      //itemList.clear();
      urlData.forEach((key, value) {
        itemList.add(value['storyUrl']);
      });

      setState(() {
        print(itemList.length);
      });
    });
  }

 loadStory() {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        itemList == null ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : Container(
          child: StoryView(
             storyItems: [
              for (var i in itemList) show(i)
            ], 
            controller: controller,
            progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
            repeat: false,
            ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  show(String urlData) {
    return StoryItem.pageImage(
      url: urlData, 
      controller: controller,
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children:<Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 5, 5),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: loadStory(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how I am navigating to that page from the main story list page that show all users who have posted a new story

```
onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StoryPageView(currentUser: currentUser.id,))),
```

And this is from my utility file I'm using to call the data

```
getStoryListData() async {
    return storyPostReference.document(currentUser.id).collection("storyPostItems").orderBy("timestamp", descending: true).snapshots();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the culprit is your `getStoryListData` , redefine it like this :

```
Future<DataSnapshot> getStoryListData() async {
  DataSnapshot snapshot= storyPostReference.document(currentUser.id).collection("storyPostItems").orderBy("timestamp", descending: true).snapshots();

print(snapshot.value); //to know whether you are making successful queries or not .
return snapshot;

  }
```

**Edit:**

Redifine your `initState` like this :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();

    crudMethods.getStoryListData().then((Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
.
.
//rest of the code
```

and your `getStoryListData` like this :

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getStoryListData() async {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshot= storyPostReference.document(currentUser.id).collection("storyPostItems").orderBy("timestamp", descending: true).snapshots();

print(snapshot.docs.toString()); //to know whether you are making successful queries or not .
return snapshot;

  }
```

Furthermore , you cant use `snapshot.value` because `QuerySnapshot` dont have any property `value` . You have to use `snapshot.docs` which returns `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>` .Iterate over the List and use `.data()` method to get a `Map<String,dynamic>` which has all the data you want .Update your code accordingly.

Comment: I tried to apply this one but it gave me the redline error ```A value of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DataSnapshot'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'DataSnapshot'.``` . I was forced to change it to something like ```Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getUserStoryData() async {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshot= storyPostReference.document(currentUser.id).collection("storyPostItems").orderBy("timestamp", descending: true).snapshots();
 return snapshot;
  }``` But I still get the same result

Comment: did you find it helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using future in the UI but returning stream from the getStoryListData() so you have to return future as
Future getStoryListData() async {
Querysnapshot snapshot= storyPostReference.document(currentUser.id).collection("storyPostItems").orderBy("timestamp", descending: true). get();
return snapshot;